# Can someone explain the following two methods in iOS and how they can be used to implement facebook share?

Tags: objective-c, ios, sharekit

I inherited a project that uses the sharekit library. I was then told by the old developer that I need to use the following methods in order to implement facebook share.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{

     [SHKFacebook handleOpenURL:url]
        return YES;
    }

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
    {

     [SHKFacebook handleOpenURL:url]
        return YES;
    }
```

I just want someone to explain to me what these two functions do and how theoretically they can be used to make facebook share work.

Answer (score 3):

Those two are sent when your application is told to open a URL, link to a file, or a file itself.  It is only sent to your application if you define the kind of URL/file you can accept in your app's info.plist.  The first one is used to gather a bit more information about the app that sent the link/file, then it let's you decide what to do with the I information (including opening the file/link).  The first one can also be used to just have info on the app that sent the URL. Like how in IOS 5 when you open the iTunes store from the Music app, it displays a new "library" button.  That way iTunes can send another URL back to the music app to relaunch the library page.

The second (in my opinion) should be deprecated because the first one provides so much more information and accomplishes the same task.

In the context of Facebook, it couldn't do much for you.  Maybe if the user needed to post a photo from an email to their wall, or maybe share a document on Facebook.

Answer (score 3):

Likely these methods implement one-half of Facebook SSO (single sign on). The way this normally works is:

1. The user clicks a button or something to "log in via Facebook"
2. You app loads the Facebook SSO login URL in safari (effectively backgrounding your own app in the process)
3. The user enters their login information in the browser and sends it to Facebook for validation.
4. On success, Facebook redirects to a URL with a specially crafted scheme (usually "fbYOUR_FB_APP_ID", so something like fb12000392304://)
5. your app registers itself as target for URLs with that scheme. Thus, when Facebook redirects to that URL, it causes your app to launch again, passing in an access_token. Because you were launched in response to opening a URL, one of the above methods will get called. At which point the SHKFacebook object apparently does something magic with said access_token.

Answer (score 1):

Both methods asks the delegate to open a resource identified by URL. `handleOpenURL` now is deprecated, you have to use `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`

Your application can provide URL Scheme Reference such as `myapp://` and you can open this app from another application by sending provided url. When application is opened then `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` will fired. You can send a query to app as well, and then parse it.

I don't know what is `SHKFacebook` and how it work, but i think it operates with these urls - [facebook schemes](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook)